# Why is the keyword `string` used to verify a variable type

Tags: string, tcl

For example, suppose we have a variable named `i` and set to `10`. To check if it is an integer, in tcl one types : `string is integer $i`.

Why is there the keyword `string` ? Does it mean the same as in python and C++ ? How to check if a tcl string (in the meaning of a sequence of characters) is a string ? `string is string $myString` does not work because `string` is not a class in tcl.

Comment: Everything is string in `Tcl`. It also has the convenience of being used as list as well.

Comment: What `string is integer $i` is doing is checking whether the string `$i` can be interpreted as an integer whose absolute value fits in 32 bits by Tcl. It does not check the type of `$i` (because everything is a string in Tcl, you can forget about data types in Tcl, but if you want more detail, you can read [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/446)).

Comment: `string is string` would be hard-coded to give boolean truth…

Answer (score 2):

Tcl doesn't have types. Or rather it does, but they're *all* serializable to strings and that happens magically behind the scenes; it looks like it doesn't have types, and you're not supposed to talk about them. Tcl does have classes, but they're not used for types of atomic values; something like `1.3` is not an instance of an object, it's just a value (often of floating point type, but it could also be a string or a singleton list or version identifier, or even a command name or variable name if you really want). Tcl's classes define objects that are commands, and those are (deliberately!) heavyweight entities.

The `string is` family of tests check whether a value meets the requirements for being interpreted as a particular kind of value. There's quite a few kinds of value, some of which make no sense as types at all (e.g., an all-uppercase string). There's nothing for `string is string` because *everything* you can ask that about would automatically pass; ***all*** values are already strings, or may be transparently converted to them.

There's exactly one way to probe what the type of a value currently is, and that is the command `::tcl::unsupported::representation` (8.6 only). That reports the current type of a value as part of its output, and you're not supposed to rely on it (there's quite a few types under the hood, many of which are pretty obscure unless you know a lot about Tcl's implementation).

```
% set s 1.3
1.3
% ::tcl::unsupported::representation $s
value is a pure string with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x100836ca0, string representation "1.3"
% expr {$s + 3}
4.3
% ::tcl::unsupported::representation $s
value is a double with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x100836ca0, internal representation 0x3ff4cccccccccccd:0x0, string representation "1.3"
```

As you can see, types are pretty flexible. You're supposed to ignore them. *We mean it.* Make your code demand the types it needs, and throw an error if it can't get them. That's what Tcl's C API does for you.